# How do I get the minimum model for a quasipoisson GLM

Tags: r

I have ran a quasipoisson GLM with the following code:

```
Output3 <- glm(GCN ~ DHSI + N + P, PondsTask2, family = quasipoisson(link = "log"))
```

and received this output:

```
  Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value   Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.69713    0.56293  -3.015    0.00272 ** 
DHSI         3.44795    0.74749   4.613 0.00000519 ***
N           -0.59648    0.36357  -1.641    0.10157    
P           -0.01964    0.37419  -0.052    0.95816    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

With the DHSI being statistically significant, but the other two variables not being significant. How do I go about dropping variables until I have the minimum model?

Comment: if they are possible covariates, or let's say factors you want to control for. you might not want to drop them. what are you using for glm for ?

Comment: So I am testing whether any of these three environmental variables explain greater crested newt (GNC) abundance, measured by a number of positive qPCR detections. Would I want to drop them?

The GNC is a count variable and the other 3 are continuous predictors.

Comment: yeah then you will fit this model with the 3 variables, and say that DHSI is the variable that explain a significant proportion of the variance in GNC, with a p-value, coeffcient of xxx, and this is all good. It's also good to know from this model that other variables do not have such a strong effect

Comment: I wouldn't go further to find the best model